# "York" is not in (or anywhere near) Camden, London

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, location

No matter how many times I try to update my ["Mailing Address" field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkaKj.png) on my careers.SO profile to my address in "York", complete with my **postcode** (in York!), upon pressing *save* it [automagically updates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIZqj.png) to "London Borough of Camden", which is [*no where close*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4bme.png).

The existing [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) reports say that these mistakes are down to Yahoo! returning the wrong results, **however**, when I [query Yahoo! directly](http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20geo.places%20where%20text=%22York%22&format=xml), I get York back as the first result, and Camden is no-where in sight.

Furthermore:

1. You are altering my input silently, without asking me to. Here's what Amazon does, and it's ohhhhh-so-better and less intrusive:

   [image]
2. This field is my mailing address; should you even be attempting to correct this? Asking Royal Mail to deliver any letters from potential employers to a city *other than the one I entered* is *wrong*. I know my address better than you, or Yahoo!, kthx.
3. Asking a potential employer to send a letter to the wrong city is a *mistake on my application*, which makes ***me*** look an idiot, which is maybe why I'm so incensed over this.

Comment: I'm scared to actually enter my post code now.

Comment: Yes. This feature should suggest, not decide for me. =)

Comment: Might it be indicating it's time to move?

Comment: @Bart: I'd rather relocate *for* a job, not to relocate so I can *find* a job :P.

Comment: It's like an inch away; geez.

Comment: This is the most intelligent, well written rant I've ever seen.

Answer (score 10):

This should be resolved, would you try it again?

You’ll love the explanation: the geocode would fail with “city, postal, country” but not with “city postal country”. In other words, the geocode service was choking on commas.

Comment: Has the process been improved so the user can override the system suggestion, or have you just fixed this particular failure with the commas?

Comment: We’ve fixed the issue with the commas. We’re not inclined to add more complexity to the UI.

Comment: @MattSherman: Thanks; I can confirm that this now updates to "York", but I still don't think my *Mailing Address* should be touched by careers.SE. I appreciate the need for you to geolocate me to show jobs *near me*, and I'm fine with it stealing my input *from* my mailing address to do this; but the result of this geolocate should ***not*** be written back to my *mailing* address.

Comment: No maps provider gets the actual name of my street correct...thankfully it is Street vs Avenue. +1 for fixing, -1 for "correcting" something that doesn't need correction.

Comment: We don’t overwrite the street part of the address; we do overwrite the city, state & country with the results of the geocode.

This is due to people entering things like “NYC” and other shortcuts. We’ve found that this minimizes error cases, but it can go in either direction: making them better or making them worse. In our experience, it makes it better the vast majority of the time.

When we encounter bugs, well, they’re bugs and it does the wrong thing, as in this case. We’re sorry for that.

Employers are not given your street address, location is determined only at city resolution.